# How to use find_all by string with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<li> <span>EAN:</span> 1111111</li>
<li> <span>Price:</span> 3</li> 
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all("li"):
   print("{0}: {1}".format(tag.name, tag.text))
```

**Output**

```
li:  EAN: 1111111<br>
li:  Price: 3
```

**Expected Output**

```
EAN: 11111
```

But how extract EAN: 11111 only? string=("EAN:") not working

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print all `li` that contains `EAN` use `soup.find_all('span',string=re.compile(r'EAN'))`:

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<li> <span>EAN:</span> 1111111</li>
<li> <span>Price:</span> 1</li> 

<li> <span>EAN:</span> 2222222</li>
<li> <span>Price:</span> 2</li> 

<li> <span>EAN:</span> 3333333</li>
<li> <span>Price:</span> 3</li> 
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('span',string=re.compile(r'EAN')):
    print(tag.parent.text)
```

**Output**

```
EAN: 1111111
EAN: 2222222
EAN: 3333333
```